# How do you make 66 using three 4s

Tags: formation-of-numbers

Rule:
allowed operations: +, −, ×,/,^,√, and ! (factorial)
example: 4^4+4!=280

Answer (score 12, accepted):

Here is one way to do it

> $66 = \left(\sqrt{\sqrt{\sqrt{4}}}\right)^{4!} + \sqrt{4}$